# Angular to Crosswalk?

Tags: angularjs, crosswalk-runtime

We are developing a complex single page app in Angularjs. Currently, we deploy this embedded in an ASP.Net web site, and also onto iOS via Cordova. This works quite well. The dream of write-once-run-everywhere is alive!

However, I've been reading about Crosswalk, and the possibility of using it to deploy simultaneously to Android, iOS, and as a Chromium app. My question is: are we going to run into security problems because Angularjs does not respect the security restrictions placed on Chromium apps?

My natural assumption was that Angularjs and Chromium would place nice together, but perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good fit for StackOverflow, questions without actual code and specific error messages/conditions are generally considered too broad.

Comment: Ah! OK. Fair enough. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this question to a different forum.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the forum where you posted please?

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk is first and foremost a WebView component with a build system and not Chromium or Google Chrome browser. At it's core it uses Chrome but there is not a concept of Chromium Apps.

There is a variant of Crosswalk which comes with Cordova plugged in. It's stable and i've used it in the past. Worth a look.

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html

I've worked with Crosswalk + Cordova (Android) and Cordova on iOS and they work together well for Hybrid apps having a single code base.